# Loop until passcode is unique

Tags: php, mysql

This is for a file sharing website. In order to make sure a "passcode", which is unique to each file, is truely unique, I'm trying this:

```
$genpasscode = mysql_real_escape_string(sha1($row['name'].time())); //Make passcode out of time + filename.
    $i = 0;
    while ($i < 1) //Create new passcode in loop until $i = 1;
    {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM files WHERE passcode='".$genpasscode."'";
        $res = mysql_query($query);
        if (mysql_num_rows($res) == 0) // Passcode doesn't exist yet? Stop making a new one!
        {
            $i = 1;
        }
        else // Passcode exists? Make a new one!
        {
            $genpasscode = mysql_real_escape_string(sha1($row['name'].time()));
        }
    }
```

This really only prevents a double passcode if two users upload a file with the same name at the *exact* same time, but hey better safe than sorry right? My question is; does this work the way I intend it to? I have no way to reliably (read: easily) test it because even one second off would generate a unique passcode anyway.

UPDATE:
Lee suggest I do it like this:

```
do {
    $query = "INSERT IGNORE INTO files 
       (filename, passcode) values ('whatever', SHA1(NOW()))";
    $res = mysql_query($query);
} while( $res && (0 == mysql_affected_rows()) )
```

[**Edit**: I updated above example to include two crucial fixes. See my answer below for details. -@Lee]

But I'm afraid it will update someone else's row. Which wouldn't be a problem if filename and passcode were the only fields in the database. But in addition to that there's also checks for mime type etc. so I was thinking of this:

```
//Add file
        $sql = "INSERT INTO files (name) VALUES ('".$str."')";
        mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

        //Add passcode to last inserted file
        $lastid = mysql_insert_id();
        $genpasscode = mysql_real_escape_string(sha1($str.$lastid.time())); //Make passcode out of time + id + filename.
        $sql = "UPDATE files SET passcode='".$genpasscode."' WHERE id=$lastid";
        mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

Would that be the best solution? The last-inserted-id field is always unique so the passcode should be too. Any thoughts?

UPDATE2: Apperenatly IGNORE does not replace a row if it already exists. This was a misunderstanding on my part, so that's probably the best way to go!

Comment: Looks ok to me. You could improve readability, using a boolean like `uniqueCodeFound` with true/false instead of an integer `i`. If you place the line with `sha1` at the begin of the while loop, you can avoid the duplicate code, generating the passcode. To test it, you can simply write $genpasscode = 'existingpasscode' after the first line.

Comment: please note: I made an adjustment to my example code (see my answer below).  The changes are minor, but they're very important.  If you're using this code in your application, then you should incorporate these changes into your code as well. Detailed explanation is in my answer below.  I also updated the excerpt of my code that is included in your post above (I did this in order to prevent others from copying the broken version by mistake in the future). Also, thanks to @martinstoeckli for pointing out the error handling issue in my original code example.

Comment: @Lee I didn't edit my actual code yet so didn't stumble upon the problem myself, glad you got it working. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Strictly speaking, your test for uniqueness won't guarantee uniqueness under a concurrent load.  The problem is that you check for uniqueness prior to (and separately from) the place where you insert a row to "claim" your newly generated passcode.  Another process could be doing the same thing, at the same time.  Here's how that goes...

Two processes generate the exact same passcode. They each begin by checking for uniqueness.  Since neither process has (yet) inserted a row to the table, both processes will find no matching passcode in database, and so both processes will assume that the code is unique.  Now as the processes each continue their work, eventually they will *both* insert a row to the `files` table using the generated code -- and thus you get a duplicate.

To get around this, you must perform the check, and do the insert in a single "atomic" operation.  Following is an explanation of this approach:

---

If you want passcode to be unique, you should define the column in your database as `UNIQUE`.  This will ensure uniqueness (even if your php code does not) by refusing to insert a row that would cause a duplicate passcode.

```
CREATE TABLE files (
  id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment PRIMARY KEY,
  filename varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  passcode varchar(64) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
)
```

Now, use mysql's `SHA1()` and `NOW()` to generate your passcode as *part of* the insert statement.  Combine this with `INSERT IGNORE ...` ([docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert.html)), and loop until a row is successfully inserted:

```
do {
    $query = "INSERT IGNORE INTO files 
       (filename, passcode) values ('whatever', SHA1(NOW()))";
    $res = mysql_query($query);
} while( $res && (0 == mysql_affected_rows()) )

if( !$res ) {
   // an error occurred (eg. lost connection, insufficient permissions on table, etc)
   // no passcode was generated.  handle the error, and either abort or retry.
} else {
   // success, unique code was generated and inserted into db.
   // you can now do a select to retrieve the generated code (described below)
   // or you can proceed with the rest of your program logic.
}
```

---

**Note:** The above example was edited to account for the excellent observations posted by @martinstoeckli in the comments section.  The following changes were made:

- changed `mysql_num_rows()` ([docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php)) to `mysql_affected_rows()` ([docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php)) -- num_rows doesn't apply to inserts.  Also removed the argument to `mysql_affected_rows()`, as this function operates on the connection level, not the result level (and in any case, the result of an insert is boolean, not a resource number).
- added error checking in the loop condition, and added a test for error/success after loop exits. The error handling is important, as without it, database errors (like lost connections, or permissions problems), will cause the loop to spin forever.  The approach shown above (using `IGNORE`, and `mysql_affected_rows()`, and testing `$res` separately for errors) allows us to distinguish these "real database errors" from the unique constraint violation (which is a completely valid non-error condition in this section of logic).

---

If you need to get the passcode after it has been generated, just select the record again:

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM files WHERE id=LAST_INSERT_ID()");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
$passcode = $row['passcode'];
```

**Edit**: changed above example to use the mysql function `LAST_INSERT_ID()`, rather than PHP's function.  This is a more efficient way to accomplish the same thing, and the resulting code is cleaner, clearer, and less cluttered.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand this a little, but wouldn't the IGNORE part cause a problem? If both processes do indeed run at the same time with the same filename, they will keep updating each other and the loop will never end?

Comment: @natli - As far as i know, the MySQL database takes care of that. There is an internal locking, and you can be sure that one of the sessions will get the lock first, and win.

Comment: @martinstoeckli Alright, that shouldn't be a problem then. Still, what if I add more fields than just name and passcode. As an example, also mime type and userID (if logged in). Wouldn't IGNORE update someone else's row if that person is uploading a file with the same filename at the exact same time?

Comment: @natli - If two sessions try to insert the same unique id, one of the sessions would be first because of the [internal locking](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/internal-locking.html). This session can insert the id. The other session has to wait until the lock is removed. Then it tries to insert the same id, but will fail and this error is given back as a warning. From the doc: _With IGNORE, the row still is not inserted..._

Comment: @martinstoeckli Doh, I read the doc wrong.. _You can use REPLACE instead of INSERT to overwrite old rows. REPLACE is the counterpart to INSERT IGNORE in the treatment of new rows that contain unique key values that duplicate old rows: The new rows are used to replace the old rows rather than being discarded_ which meant REPLACE does that, not ignore.. my bad. Thanks!

Comment: @natli - Well, i made a test myself and it seems to me, that the example is buggy. Neither should `mysql_num_rows` be used after executing an INSERT statement, nor is the result of `mysql_query()` an integer. Instead we can write `mysql_query("INSERT INTO files...")` and get back true if the id could be created, or false if the id already exists. The keyword IGNORE won't give us this information.

Comment: @Lee - I suggest changing your example like that:
`do {
  $id = SHA1(NOW());
  $query = "INSERT INTO files
    (filename, passcode) values ('whatever', '$id')";
  $res = mysql_query($query);
} while ($res == false)`
This way you catch the error in $res and have the valid $id for free.

Comment: @martinstoeckli - good catch (example updated).  You're right of course: `mysql_num_rows()` does not work with `INSERT`s.  I meant to use `mysql_affected_rows()`, which *does* work for this purpose.  I've also added error handling, but I've used a slightly different strategy than you recommended.  My approach allows to distinguish between the unique constraint violation (a completely valid non-error condition), and a true database error (eg. lost connection to db). The distinction is important so as to avoid an infinite loop in the case of connection problems, or other "true" db errors.

Answer (score 3):

I'd personally would have write it on a different way but I'll provide you a much easier solution: sessions.

I guess you're familiar with sessions? Sessions are server-side remembered variables that timeout at some point, depending on the server configuration (the default value is 10 minutes or longer). The session is linked to a client using a session id, a random generated string.

If you start a session at the upload page, an id will be generated which is guaranteed to be unique as long the session is not destroyed, which should take about 10 minutes. That means that when you're combining the session id and the current time you'll never have the same passcode. A session id + the current time (in microseconds, milliseconds or seconds) are NEVER the same.

In your upload page:

```
session_start();
```

In the page where you handle the upload:

```
$genpasscode = mysql_real_escape_string(sha1($row['name'].time().session_id()));
// No need for the slow, whacky while loop, insert immediately
// Optionally you can destroy the session id
```

If you do destroy the session id, that would mean there's a very slim chance that another client can generate the same session id so I wouldn't advice that. I'd just allow the session to expire.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is:

> does this work the way I intend it to?

Well, I'd say... yes, it does work, but it could be optimized.

**Database**

To make sure to not have the same value in the field `passcode` on the database layer, add a unique key to this:

```
/* SQL */
ALTER TABLE `yourtable` ADD UNIQUE `passcode` (`passcode`);
```

(duplicate key handling has to be taken care of than ofc)

**Code**

To wait a second until a new Hash is created, is ok, but if you're talking heavy load, then a single second might be a tiny eternity. Therefore I'd rather add another component to the `sha1`-part of your code, maybe a file id from the same database record, userid or whatever which makes this really unique.

If you don't have a unique id at hand, you still can fall back to a random number [`rand`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php)-function in php.

I don't think [mysql_real_escape_string](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) is needed in this context. The [`sha1`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sha1.php) returns a 40-character hexadecimal number anyway, even if there are some bad characters in your rows.

```
$genpasscode = sha1(rand().$row['name'].time());
```

...should suffice.

**Style**

Two times the passcode generation code is used in your code sample. Start cleaning this up in moving this into a function.

```
$genpasscode = gen_pc(row['name']);

...

function gen_pc($x) 
{
  return sha1($row[rand().$x.time());
}
```

If I'd do it, I'd do it differently, I'd use the [`session_id()`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php) to avoid duplicates as good as possible. This way you wouldn't need to loop and communicate with your database in that loop possibly several times.

Comment: Very true. Generating random numbers is a science for itself, I didn't want to get too deep into this in this post!

Answer (score 1):

You can add unique constraint to your table.

```
ALTER TABLE files ADD UNIQUE (passcode);
```

PS: You can use `microtime` or `uniqid` to make the passcode more unique.

**Edit:**
You make your best to generate a unique value in php, and unique constraint is used to guarantee that at database side. If your unique value is very unique, but in very rare case it  failed to be unique, just feel free to give the message like `The system is busy now. Please try again:)`.

Comment: What would the default action be if it tries to insert a passcode that already exists? Would the insert just not go through? That wouldn't be very good.

Comment: @nalti The unique constraint is used to insurance the unique value at database level.

Comment: The `mysql_query()` function would just return false, if the id already exists.